# Change from BibTeX to BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I have a BibTeX library exported from EndNote. I'm writing a thesis and, in order to have bibliographies for each chapter, I'm trying to switch to BibLaTeX. My .tex file, which compiles perfectly fine when using BibTeX, gives the following error message when I try to compile it using biber:

```
ERROR - BibTeX subsystem: C:\Users\esukeo\AppData\Local\Temp\wQX37mGMgn\endref.bib_5600.utf8, line 2, syntax error: found "=", expected ","
```

As I see it (I'm still fairly inexperienced), the `.bib` file which works fine in BibTeX is formatted so it is incompatible with the BibLaTeX compiler. An example entry from the `.bib` file:

```
@article{Ash07,
   author = {Ashley, T. and Buckle, L. and Datta, S. and Emeny, M. T. and Hayes, D. G. and Hilton, K. P. and Jefferies, R. and Martin, T. and Phillips, T. and WaIiis, D. J. and Wilding, P. J. and Chan, R.},
   title = {Heterogeneous InSb quantum well transistors on silicon for ultra-high speed, low power logic applications},
   journal = {Electronics Letters},
   volume = {43},
   number = {14},
   pages = {777-779},
   year = {2007},
   abstract = {<removed>},
   ISSN = {0013-5194},
   DOI = {10.1049/el:20071335},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
```

Is there a solution in the BibLaTeX build process? If not, can I have chapter bibliographies using BibTeX? Manually editing the `.bib` file is not an option, as there are hundreds of entries.

I am using TeXstudio, reinstalled today when this problem started, so it and MiKTeX are up to date. TeXstudio has been configured to compile using `biber`

Comment: You probably have an "=" in one of your keys. biblatex doesn't like this. e.g. `@article{Ash=07,` would give this error.

Comment: The top entry in the .bib is as follows:

    @article{
       author = {Adibi, Ali and Lin, Shawn-Yu and Scherer, Axel and Peters, David W. and Davids, Paul S. and Kim, Jin K. and Leonhardt, Darin and Beechem, Thomas E. and Howell, Stephen W. and Ohta, Taisuke and Wendt, Joel R. and Montoya, John A.},
       title = {Application of plasmonic subwavelength structuring to enhance infrared detection},
       volume = {8994},
       pages = {899419},
       year = {2014},
       ISSN = {0277786X},
       DOI = {10.1117/12.2040727},
       type = {Journal Article}
    }

Continued...

Comment: As the .bib is exported from EndNote, most entries don't have a label and cut straight to 'author'. I'd presumed this would be an acceptable way to start an entry but apparently it isn't

Comment: No, you need a key/label, without it you can't cite the entry.

Comment: I've labeled the ones I'm going to cite but there are other, unlabelled, entries in the database. I share the EndNote database and can't delete them, so I left the unlabelled. This was fine in BibTeX and I don't know if it matters for BibLaTeX

Comment: @OVavasour As a test, can you make a copy of the .bib file and delete all entries without a label?

Comment: Off-topic: You encase `InSb` (Indium-Antimonide, right?) in curly braces -- like so: `{InSb}` -- to make sure that the letters "I" and "S" won't get converted to lowercase if sentence style formatting is in effect.

Comment: @Mico: That's a temporary bib-file from biber. I get e.g. (from test.bib) an error in `\test.bib_11124.utf8`.

Comment: If endnote exports `.bib` files without keys then its export feature is broken. Period. It is broken for BibTeX as well as Biblatex/Biber. (Maybe BibTeX tolerates it, but it is broken nonetheless.) All of the (free) online services I've used providing `.bib` export get at least this right, whatever else they screw up.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help everyone. The .tex file compiled after I went back to the .bib file, removed the unlabeled entries and tidied all the remaining entries so they fit LaTeX syntax. The problem is in the .bib file and the export from EndNote to .bib - BibTeX tolerated EndNote's perculiar formatting but Biber does not.